# C# компиляция готового проекта

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Недавно открыл для себя очень хорошую функцию .NET приложений. Весь код у них после компиляции остаётся в неизменном виде. Т.е. используя программу декомпилятор (я использую JetBrains dotPeek) *.dll или *.exe можно весь код восстановить в первоначальном состоянии, включая комментарии. Всё было хорошо, когда из сторонней библиотеки нужно взять один класс в своё приложении и полностью от неё отказаться. Но теперь моё приложение спокойно можно прочитать включая мои комментарии в коде.

Теперь сам вопрос: Можно ли откомпилировать проект без возможности реверса кода?

P.S. Может в Visual Studio для публикации конечной версии нужно сделать что-то иное, кроме как указать текущий вариант Debug/Release?

Comment: Вы хотите приожения-обсфукаторы. Во-первых, код декомпилируется не 100% точно. Во-вторых, защита не 100%тная (да и для других языков тоже нет). В-третьих, обсфукация мешает работе приложения. Я бы не рекомендовал так делать.

Comment: Это называется Обфускация. Хороший обфускатор стоит денег. Если вы пишите для души и для народу, то лучше не заморачиваться по этому поводу, а может и вовсе выложить код на GitHub, тогда получите много приимуществ (скажем, лицензию JetBrains). Если вы пишите для компании, то это должна мне кажется уже сама компания решать, что и чем закрывать.

Comment: Вы знаете, для приложения уровня "Калькулятор" я с вами полностью согласен. Но когда проект гораздо больше, то хотелось бы просто скрыть свой код сделав его трудно читаемым, и самое главное, без комментариев в коде. Ибо в том виде, в котором я его увидел он ничем не отличается от кода с GitHub. Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Вы не пытались воссоздать реально проэкт с помощью JetBrains - поэтому не сталкивались - что "воссозданый" проэкт не компилируется. Комментарии с кода по-моему не линкуются в exe-шник, тут что-то другое имеется ввиду. Возможно вы создали debug версию. Попробуйте удалить pdb файл (если он есть)

Comment: Я не говорил о компиляции воссозданного проекта. Важно не это. Важно скрыть готовое решение, в которое в худшем случае придётся внести несколько правок и не писать с нуля. Я не считаю свой код хорошим, но он реализует те знания, которые я хотел бы скрыть от посторонних глаз. Есть некоторые задачи реализация которых не так уж и трудна, чем понимание как это работает.

Comment: Комментариев в дизассемблированном коде не будет. Точно так же, как и имён локальных переменных. Имена параметров и классов будут.